# Is it okay to store a digital signature and the public key of the signatory inside a json file?

Tags: node.js, json, encryption, cryptography, digital-signature

In my project, I am signing a string with my private key. If I store my public key and the signature in a json file that is later to be verified, then is it really safe? Or is using PKCS#7 preferred? If yes, then what would be the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As long as your private key remains undisclosed, storing your public key along with a document signed by the private key is safe.

In the SAML2.0 system for federated user authentication and authorization, the Assertion tokens they use are signed with a private key. Those Assertions are XML documents, containing both the crypto signature and the public key. The public key is the base64 encoded version of the X.509 public key in that system.

Of course, a recipient should validate the signature with its own previously stored copy of the public key. If a recipient validates the signature with the public key in the document, it's vulnerable to spoofing. A bad actor could sign a malicious document with their own private key, and send along their own public key. The signature would match, but prove nothing about the origin of the document.

Comment: Thanks @O.Jones. So, would having a Certification Authority might help here if the verifying party does not have the signatory's public key?

Comment: It all depends on the workflow of your application. Please go to https://security.stackexchange.com/ and ask a specific question.